# Why does Imgur say Upload failed, remote server returned an error: File is over the size limit (using Obsidian Plugin)

Tags: imgur

Why does Imgur say Upload failed, remote server returned an error: File is over the size limit (using Obsidian Plugin)

https://youtu.be/wYz_hJsGnQk

Comment: This is a 1 minute YouTube video showing my issue with Imgur and Obsidian Plugin: https://youtu.be/wYz_hJsGnQk

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The edit queue is full, so I'll leave this comment instead. The error (from the video) is: "Upload failed, remote server returned an error: File is over the size limit." And the image you're trying to upload is 711KB. I don't see why that should be too big.